# Best way to programmatically create categories?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, import

We're working on an XML import plugin to migrate content from another CMS.

What's the best way to create a new category (with a name, slug etc.) and assign it to the entry when running 
`$entryModel = new EntryModel();` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a category, you'd have to use the [`craft()->categories->saveCategory()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/CategoriesService#saveCategory-detail) method, and feed it a CategoryModel. Having done that, you can use the ID of your new category to create an array for the entry's category field (in this example its handle is `categoryFieldHandle`):

```
$category = new CategoryModel();
$category->groupId = 2; // Or whatever ID your new category's group has.
$category->getContent()->title = 'My new category title'; // Slug will be automagically created

if(craft()->categories->saveCategory($category)) {
    $entryModel = new EntryModel();
    $entryModel->title = 'My entry's title';
    $entryModel->categoryFieldHandle[] = $category->id;

    if(craft()->entries->saveEntry($entryModel)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that more than one entry will have the same category, you might also need to add a conditional to check whether the category already exists.

Comment: +1 to what @DouglasMcDonald said - I'm working through that right now.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald, how would I do that? Is there a specific utility method for that purpose? Thanks!

Comment: @Floriskoch No special utility methods. You would just need to test for the existence of the category using the groupId and category title. I would probably use an `ElementCriteriaModel` for this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Paul Verheul's excellent answer (and to answer question by Floriskoch) — to test for the existence of a category before creating it, you might try something like the following (untested).

```
// Get category group from known id
$categoryGroup = craft()->categories->getGroupById(2);

// Find categories matching group and title
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->group = $categoryGroup;
$criteria->title = "My Category Title";
$criteria->limit = null;
$categories = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);

// 1 or more matching categories exist; select first category
if($categories) {
    $categoryId = $categories[0]->id; // only want first category if more than one with the same title

// no categories exist; create category
} else {
    $category = new CategoryModel();
    $category->groupId = 2;
    $category->getContent()->title = 'My new category title';
    if(craft()->categories->saveCategory($category)) {
        $categoryId = $category->id;
    }
}

// double check we have a category id
if($categoryId) {
    $entryModel = new EntryModel();
    $entryModel->title = 'My entry's title';
    $entryModel->myCategoryFieldHandle[] = $categoryId;

    if(craft()->entries->saveEntry($entryModel)) {
        ...
    }
}
```